# awk: automatically call functions from file

Tags: awk, gawk

I need to perform the absolute value calculation a lot in `awk`.

But absolute value is not built into `awk`, so many of my `awk` commands look like this:

```
awk  'function abs(x){return ((x < 0.0) ? -x : x)}  { ...calls to "abs" .... }'  file
```

**Is there a way to store user-defined `awk` functions in files, and have `awk` automatically load these functions whenever it is called?**

Something like setting an `awk` "include" path or user-profile, much the same way you do for bash and other programs.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Include-Files.html#Include-Files

Comment: As the link @Basilevs posted states, you can use `@include "file"` to import files.

Comment: I guess you could also alias `awk` to `awk -i funcs.awk`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@include "file"` to import files.

e.g. Create a file named `func_lib`:

```
function abs(x){
    return ((x < 0.0) ? -x : x)
}
```

Then include it with `awk`:

```
awk '@include "func_lib"; { ...calls to "abs" .... }'  file
```

Comment: but then I have to do this every time...   i suppose Mark Setchell's comment is best

Comment: For your specific use, perhaps it is best.  It depends how you want to call `awk`.  It might make sense to only include it for the specific `awk` programs which need the external functions.  Also, if using an `awk` script, it seems more practical to do all the `@include`s at the top instead of passing each to the `-i` command line argument.

Answer (score 0):

Also try

```
$ cat function_lib.awk
  function abs(x){
      return ((x < 0.0) ? -x : x)
 }
```

call function like this

```
$ awk -f function_lib.awk --source 'BEGIN{ print abs(-1)}'
```